# AWS Permanent Redirect Error with Paperclip & Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

Up until today, I have had no issues setting up S3 on my development environment. I am now constantly getting the following permanent redirect error:

```
AWS::S3::Errors::PermanentRedirect at /locations/1
The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
```

Paperclip is working perfectly fine. The issue only arose when I tried to move hosting images onto S3.

---

1/ the AWS-SDK gems is installed

```
// gemfile

gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
```

---

2/ Paperclip defaults are properly setup; both access keys are configured correctly in my `bash_profile`

```
//development.rb

config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => 'traipse-temp',
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
 }
```

---

3/ I have a S3 bucket created titled "traipse-temp" set to `US Standard`

---

Does anyone have any insight as to why I am receiving a permanent redirect error? I have setup 4 other applications this exact same why but only with this latest project did I receive this first-time error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution?